# Unable to Save Nmap output in terminal using Kali Linux

Tags: linux, debian, nmap

I'll begin with saying I am a newcomer, and as so, this question may seem simple or stupid, but, in Ubuntu a command like this:

```
root@kali:~# nmap -F  scanme.nmap.org> /Desktop/text.txt
```

would save the output file as text.txt onto my desktop but this doesn't seem to work on Kali...
I have also tried:

```
root@kali:~# nmap -F  scanme.nmap.org > /home/Desktop/text.txt
```

my error is:

```
bash: /Desktop/text.txt: Not a directory
```

I'm sure this is just something that I am missing, but I am very new to Kali, as I am just reading about internet security, routers, firewalls etc.

Also if there are other questions like this, I have not yet found it, sorry if it is a duplicate in advance!

Comment: There is unlikely to be any such directory as `/Desktop` or `/home/Desktop` on a Linux system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `/home/root/Desktop/text.txt`

advice: use tab for autocompletion, so you can't rly make any mistakes.

also try `pwd` to print the directory you are actually in, e.g.:

```
f00@myBox:~$ pwd
/home/f00
```

..the syntax to save your nmap-results to a file would be:

```
#nmap –oN /home/yourUser/someDirectory/text.txt scanme.nmap.org
```

Comment: Ah! I finally got back to the grind and found that you don't actually start with the home directory....pwd starts at root, not home....sigh...Thank you for helping me sort out my stupid assumption!